# Highchart merge values with same date

Tags: php, highcharts

Hey i'm trying to make a highchart which show the current balance from different transactions. The problem is that there can be several transactions in one day and thereby it creates an quite strange looking graph. How can i merge the values with same date so it does not look so strange.

Image:

[image]

So basically i have following dataset which is queried in $balancequery, as you can see some of them has same date.

[image]

Below is the data where i first loop through the query and save the value/balance and date in a data array and populate in chart.

```
<?

$data = array();
foreach ($balanceQuery as $row) 
{ 

    $value = $row->balance;

    $datetime1 = date('Y, n, j', strtotime($row->post_date. '-1 month'));

    $datetime = 'Date.UTC('. $datetime1 .')';
    $data[] = "[$datetime, $value]";
}


?>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var chart;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'chart-container',
                        type: 'line',
                        margintop: 30
                    },
                    title: {
        text: ''
    },

                    xAxis: {

                        type: 'datetime',
                        dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
                            day: '%e. %b'    
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        }
                    },

                    exporting: { enabled: false },
    credits: {
    enabled: false
     },

                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },

                    },


                    series: [{
                        showInLegend: false,
                        name: 'Profit',
                        data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>]

                    }]

                });
            });

        });

        </script>
```

Comment: Are you not using the H:M:S information? Or are the points too close to see the angle? With H:M:S I'd think this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: i've tried to add H:i:s after Y, j, n but then the chart disappear?

Comment: I see. Didn't read the whole thing. I guess it would be `'Y, n, j, H, i, s'`..? Tried that?

Comment: Or why don't you convert dates to timestamp in the backend? Like this: `$datetime = strtotime($row->post_date) * 1000;`